# jquery datatable numeric sort issues

Tags: jquery, html, datatable

I have integrated the datatable script for my table. I have the rank column. The data are like

[image]

I need the numeric sort here. For this i used the following code

```
{ "sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [ 0 ] }
```

In html code i used the following

```
<span style="display:none;">3</span> #3 in
<span style="display:none;">45</span> #45 in
<span style="display:none;">25</span> #25 in
<span style="display:none;">25</span> #15 in etc...
```

So in span tag i showed the numbers in hidden format.

But the sorting is not working for this cell. Please help me. Thanks

**Updated On Dec15
=====================**

```
{ "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [8] }, //set column visibility            
                {"sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [8] }, //define data type for specified columns
                {"iDataSort": 8, "aTargets": [3] } //sort based on a hidden column when another column is clicked 
                { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [9] }, //set column visibility            
                {"sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [9] }, //define data type for specified columns
                {"iDataSort": 9, "aTargets": [5] } //sort based on a hidden column when another column is clicked
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way of solving your problem. 
Put the numeric values in a hidden column instead of the hidden span. In your datatables binding, point to the hidden column when the visible column header is clicked like this:

```
myTable.dataTable({        
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [hiddenColumnIndex] }, //set column visibility            
        {"sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [hiddenColumnIndex] }, //define data type for specified columns
        {"iDataSort": hiddenColumnIndex, "aTargets": [visibleColumnIndex] } //sort based on a hidden column when another column is clicked            
    ]
});​
```

Comment: I used the above code. But the entire sorting is not working. I dont know, what i am wrong. Here is my code  "aoColumnDefs": [
     { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0] },
     { "bVisible": false, "aTargets": [8] }, //set column visibility            
     {"sType": "numeric", "aTargets": [8] }, //define data type for specified columns
     {"iDataSort": [8], "aTargets": [3] }, //sort based on a hidden column when another column is clicked        
     
    ],

Comment: Sorry i found what the mistake is. Your code is working fine. Thanks

Comment: I updated my question. Here Shall we use 2 hidden columns for 2 different targets. i.e Cell8 is is hidden for for cell 3. Respectively i used cell 9 is hidden for cell 5. For this i used the above code (Updated in my question Under "Updated On Dec15 "). Is this any wrong here?

Comment: Yes, for adding another target/hidden columns, just add another line of `{"iDataSort": hiddenColumnIndex, "aTargets": [visibleColumnIndex] }`.

Comment: Oh. Thankyou. For default sorting i used "aaSorting": [[ 8, 'asc' ]] . But 8 is the hidden column. The target column is 3. The sorting works fine. But the table head cell arrow is not highlighted for cell 3. Is there any way to highlight?

Comment: Just apply a class to the header whenever the header is clicked. As for the initial page load, add the class to the column header 3 so that the class is applied initially.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using the datatables.net jquery plugin.  If your underlying data is numeric, then use the [mRender option](http://www.datatables.net/usage/columns) to override the html rendered in the table cell (i.e., format the number to display #[actual number] in).  With sorting enabled it should sort on the underlying data (refer to mData option).  Note: This is for the current version of the plugin... if you have an older version then refer fnRender option.

For example:

```
"aoColumns": [
  { "mData": "StringColumn1" },
  { "mData": "StringColumn2" },
  {
    "mData": "Your Numeric Column",
    "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
                 return '#' + data + ' in';
               }
  }
```